# How can I populate an array in Bash Shell script loop

Tags: bash, shell-script

`cmdline> ls -la /.myScript.sh`

```
   set index=0
    set usrlist[index]="null" 


        while read line
        do

        #Total lines read
        z=`echo $line| wc -l`
        lines=`expr $lines + $z`    

        # 2) #total unique user
        linesED=`echo $line | sed 's/[0-9]//g'`
        linesEDA=`echo ${linesED:10}` 
        userr=`echo $linesEDA | awk '{print $1}'`  

        for i in z
        do
            usrlist[i]=$userr
        done
            index=`expr $index + $i`
            echo ${usrlist[index]}# prints out data correctly but with 
                                  #error expr:non-integer argument 
        done
 echo ${usrlist[index]}#here blank output only
```

I want to print out all the memebers of array at end, without error

Comment: Take a look at: http://www.shellcheck.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to introduce a file for `done` of `while` such as :

```
done < myfile.txt
```

Comment: thank you , but I managed to do it in another way..thanks for the help though